# Why this regular expression fails the last match

Tags: c#, regex

I have this resumed animation data list with the most representative formats:

```
    * » iddle 1-210
    * » run01 215-252
    * » stand up 876-987
0   -      = bindpose
1   - 48   = idle
118 - 150  = attack_idle
151 - 192  = attack 1
791 - 815  = strafe right
000 - 009 T-pose
010 - 040 walk
045 - 075 walk-back
080 - 110 walk-right-45
490 - 590 idle-1
1060 - 1120 spell-cast_01
1515 - 1590 sack_pick_up
```

I'm figuring how to match animation names...

I've made this match pattern,

```
 ([a-zA-Z][\w- _]+)
```

It returns

```
1: iddle 1-210
1: run01 215-252
1: stand up 876-987
1: bindpose
1: idle
1: attack_idle
1: attack 1
1: strafe right
1: T-pose
1: walk
1: walk-back
1: walk-right-45
1: idle-1
1: spell-cast_01
1: sack_pick_up
```

To avoid that the three starting matches contain numbers, I have tried this:

```
 ([a-zA-Z][\w- _]+)(?:\s\d+\s*[-]*\s*\d\s*)
```

but it does not match the last line:

```
1: iddle
1: run01
1: stand up
1: bindpose
1: idle
1: attack_idle
1: attack 1
1: strafe right
1: T-pose
1: walk
1: walk-back
1: walk-right-45
1: idle-1
1: spell-cast_01
```

Why?

I think is related to (?=**\s** but I have not found how to fix it...

EDIT: Fixed the '|' between brackets

Comment: Don't use `|` in character classes (`[]`). There is an implicit `|` between every character.

Comment: Uupps... you are right... I'm not used to regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex to capture only names in `group1`

```
^.*?([a-zA-Z][\w -]+?)(?:(?:\s*\d+-\d+)?)$
```

Use `multiline` mode

---

**Errors** in your regex

the `_` in `[\w- _]` is not needed since `\w` contains `_`

the `\w-` in `[\w- _]` is wrong since you are specifying a range between `\w` and space.

It should be `[\w -]` since `-` when used at **start** or **end** of the character class doesnt have any special meaning

Comment: The best results... whitout doubts... http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=a1d11ad4-5deb-4527-b31b-e922b0007eea  why you use "(?:" twice? and I don't understand why you use '?' so many times and what is the purpose...

Comment: @Ωmega `.*?` is valid else it would only match the last character...plz just think before u act..r u a small kid running viral in so..

Comment: @Blau `.*?` is needed to capture everthing till the first character i.e a-zA-Z..if you use `.*` then it would match greedily matching the last character only!..try it yourself and you would come to know the diff between `.*` and `.*?`

Comment: @Ωmega check out what it captures when u use `.*` instead of `.*?` [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=2abbd1e2-ebb0-4c2d-bfeb-c47dd9e121cf)

Comment: @Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It - Are you blind or what? Who told you to use `.*` instead of `.*?`? Nobody. I told you to remove `^.*?` part from the beginning, as it is not needed. Do you speek English?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern

```
[a-zA-Z][\w-]*(\s+(?:[a-zA-Z]|\d(?!\d*-))[\w-]*)*
```

Comment: Adding multiline and () to group it does the job http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=649d9441-cd48-4b7a-b43b-b446b9fe81de

Answer (score 1):

I think all your other lines are able to match the line break with `\s` and the `1` at the next line with `\d+`, which is not possible in the last line. Here is a different option:

If you use the multiline option (in C# you can provide the match function with the parameter `RegexOptions.Multiline`), `$` will match the end of the line. Then you could do something like this:

```
([a-zA-Z][\w -]+)(?:\s\d+\s*-*\s*\d+)?$
```

This makes the number part at the end optional, but asserts that there has to be a line-ending afterwards.

Note that I removed `_` from the character class, because it is already part of `\w`. I also change `[-]` to  `-`, because it is equivalent.

Comment: It is better with multiline but continues matching numbers at the end.. http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=336f7f56-9e38-40b5-93d3-54c229f23a1b

Comment: @Blau, sorry add a `?` after the first `+`. Now it shouldn't consume the numbers. Your animation name will then be found in the first capturing group.

Comment: is right adding that, is adding ´?´ is the way to relate a group match with the ´(?:´ statement?

Comment: I mean this: `([a-zA-Z][\w -]+?)(?:\s\d+\s*-*\s*\d+)?$`. In this case `?` has nothing to do with `(?:` but just makes the `+` ungreedy, taking in as little as possible.